# ListView and Checkbox - Checkbox not being ticked as in tutorials

Tags: android, cursor, simplecursoradapter

I have been reading tutorials and forum posts for the past few hours to try and get a simple checkbox listview implemented.

I understand (i believe) how I need to maintain the state of my checkboxes in a list (o in my case a map).

It is such a simple thing I am sure but my checkbox is not being set to true or false in my bindView method. Here is the code

```
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        final int rowId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));

        familyText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_row_family_name);
        markedBox = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_row_check);
        familyText.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));



        view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Log.d("OnClick","Row clicked");
                boolean currentlyChecked;

                if(checkedState.size() >= rowId){
                    currentlyChecked = checkedState.get(rowId);
                    checkedState.put(rowId, !currentlyChecked);
                }else{
                    currentlyChecked = false;
                    checkedState.put(rowId, !currentlyChecked);
                }

                markedBox.setChecked(checkedState.get(rowId));

            }

        });

        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);


    }
```

Here is the declaration of checkedState. This is class member of my Activity.

```
private Map<Integer, Boolean> checkedState = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();
```

As far as I can make out I should have a listener on the row (this works because my Log message prints correctly) but the Checkbox doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

I was incorrect that my checkboxes weren't being checked. Just the wrong one is being checked. I will close this question.